# Iterating over ConcurrentSkipListSet with different thread removing elements

Tags: java, multithreading, set, java.util.concurrent

I have a `ConcurrentSKipListSet`, and I'm iterating over values in this set with a `for-each` loop. 
Another thread at some point is going to remove an element from this set.

I think I'm running into a situation where one thread removes an element that I'm yet to iterate over (or maybe I've just started to iterate over it) and so a call being made from within the loop fails.

Some code for clarity:

```
for(Foo foo : fooSet) {
  //do stuff

  //At this point in time, another thread removes this element from the set

  //do some more stuff
  callService(foo.getId()); // Fails
}
```

Reading the docs I can't work out if this is possible or not:

> Iterators are weakly consistent, returning elements reflecting the state of the set at some point at or since the creation of the iterator. They do not throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, and may proceed concurrently with other operations.

So is this possible, and if so, what's a good way of handling this?

Thanks

Will

Comment: @newuser Could you clarify - what do you mean by reduce?

Comment: sorry i latterly noticed the word thread

Comment: @Will: What do you mean with "fails"?

Comment: @Will try this :  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

Comment: @EnnoShioji  the service doesn't like the call - IE it's invalid now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think I'm running into a situation where one thread removes an element that I'm yet to iterate over (or maybe I've just started to iterate over it) and so a call being made from within the loop fails.

I don't think that's what the javadocs are saying:

> Iterators are weakly consistent, returning elements reflecting the state of the set at some point at or since the creation of the iterator. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException, and may proceed concurrently with other operations.

This is saying that you don't have to worry about someone removing from the `ConcurrentSkipListSet` at the same time that you are iterating across the list.  There certainly *is* going to be a race condition as you are moving across the iterator however.  Either `foo` gets removed right *after* your iterator gets it or it was removed right before and the iterator doesn't see it.

> callService(foo.getId()); // this shouldn't "fail"

If `foo` gets returned by the iterator, your service call won't "fail" unless it is assuming that the `foo` is still in the list and somehow checking it.  The worst case is that you might do some operations on `foo` and call the service with it even though it was just  removed from the list by the other thread.

Comment: I understand - thanks for the clarification. My problem is that the service no longer expects to receive `foo`. I think I need to re work how the service handles this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've hit this problem as well with queues that are written to and read by different threads. One approach is to mark instead of remove elements that are no longer needed. You can run a cleanup iterator after you go through the whole list. You need a global lock just for removing elements from the list, and the rest of the time your code can run in parallel. Schematically it works like this:

```
writer:
  while() {
    set.add(something);
    something.markForDelete();
  }

reader:
  while() {
    // process async
    iterator iter = set.getIterator();
    for(iter.hasNext()) {
      ... work, check isMarkedForDelete() ...
    }
    iter = set.getIterator();

    // delete, sync
    globalLock.Lock();
    for(iter.hasNext()) {
      if(something.isMarkedForDelete()) {
      set.remove(something);
    }
    globalLock.Unlock();
  }
}
```